# Custom Heroku domain will not reflect upgrade from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I am using Automated Certificate Management that Heroku makes available for apps with paid dynos. **my_app.herokuapp.com** accurately reflects the SSL certificate and loads as a HTTPS:// page.

But my custom domain, **www.my_app.com** doesn't load as HTTPS://

My custom domain is from Google Domains and here is the CNAME mapping -

**Custom Resource Records**
www is mapped to www.my_app.com.herokudns.com.

**Subdomain forward**
my_app.com --> https://www.my_app.com

Any thoughts on where I could be going wrong? I can't seem to find step-by-step instruction anywhere, please point me to any resources you all found to be useful.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but do you have `config.force_ssl = true` in your production.rb?

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a ton.